# How do I stop the movement function html5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

If I use code like this

> if (this.x > 650)
>
> this.x += this.speed;
>
> }
>
> else if ( this.x =650){
>
> this.x = (stop moving);
>
> ### }

Objects will move

> if (this.x > 650)
>
> this.x += this.speed;
>
> }

How do I get when the object is at x = 650. This function 'this.x += this.speed;' will stop?

Comment: What your initial value of `this.x`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to subtract this.speed from this.x, because your if statement saying the this.x is more than 650 then add this.speed to this.x, but if you're going to add speed, you would never reach else, because your this.x would be always greater.